# Firefox Addon parent.document permission denied error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, firefox-addon-sdk

Im working on a firefox addon in which I append some html and javascript to the page DOM. Now on certain sites, iframes exist but I do not want to append my HTML to those iframes, I want it only attached to the main page DOM. To do that I tried

```
if (window.top === self) {
   $('html').append(html);
} else {
    $(parent.document.body).append(html);
}
```

This appends the html, but the javascript doesn't work, with the error message `Permission denied to access property "document"`. I tried using `.first()` combinations with body and document but none of them worked out. Any advice on how I can do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: since this is normal  javascript you cannot access dom of parent  from a iframe .however from a firefox addon you can surely do this .read this  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Cross_Domain_Content_Scripts\

Comment: I dont wanna do that  thsts the thing. I wanna just add to the parent DOM and pretend that the iframes dont exist

Comment: @irtzaqc you cannot add to the parents dom without set permissions. think : a advertisement loaded to a iframe .if advertisement can replace main page it's a big risk.

Comment: I think im not explaining myself correctly. I want to add html to the main page dom from my addon. But the code I use adds the html to any iframes as well. How do I bypass that